# Storing an anonymous function passed as a parameter in a Map

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a simple web application server as a personal project to improve my Scala, but I've hit upon a problem.

I'd like to be able to set up routes using code like the following:

```
def routes()
{
    get("/wobble")
    {
        ...many lines of code here...
    }

    get("/wibble")
    {
        ...many lines of code here...
    }

    post("/wibble")
    {
        ...many lines of code here...
    }

    post("/wobble")
    {
        ...many lines of code here...
    }
}
```

`routes` is called by the server when it starts and `get` and `post` are functions defined by me like this:

```
get(url:String)(func:()=>String)=addroute("GET",url,func)
post(url:String(func:()=>String)=addroute("POST",url,func)

addroute(method:String,url:String,f:()=>String)
{
    routesmap+=(method->Map[String,()=>String](url,func))
}
```

Unfortunately, I've had nothing but problems with this. Could anyone tell me the *correct* way in Scala to add an anonymous function (as passed in as a parameter in the defined `routes` function above) to a Map (or any other Scala collection for that matter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, this one ? :

```
type Fonc = ( (=> String) => Unit)

var routesmap = Map[String,Map[String,()=>String]]()

def addRoute(method:String,url:String,f:()=>String) = {     

routesmap+=(method-> (routesmap.getOrElse(method,Map[String,()=>String]()) + (url->f)))

}

def get(url:String):Fonc = (x => addRoute("GET",url,() => x))
def post(url:String):Fonc = (x => addRoute("POST",url,() => x))

def routes() 
{
post("/wobble")
{
"toto"
}

get("/wibble")
{
"titi"
}

}
```

Comment: Wow. That's just blown my mind. It works exactly as I want it to - I just wish I could understand exactly how...

Comment: Hm, I think I'm close.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517451/any-does-not-take-parameters-storing-unit-functions-in-a-scala-hashmap Any looks please?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```
scala> var funcs = Map[String,(Int)=>Int]()
funcs: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int => Int] = Map()

scala> funcs += ("time10", i => i * 10 )

scala> funcs += ("add2", i => i + 2 )

scala> funcs("add2")(3)
res3: Int = 5

scala> funcs("time10")(10)
res4: Int = 100
```

You can also add a declared function:

```
val minus5 = (i:Int) => i - 5
funcs += ( "minus5", minus5)
```

Or a method:

```
def square(i: Int) = i*i
funcs += ("square", square)
```

In your case, you can have two maps, one for `GET` and one for `POST`. It should simplify the design (and at most, you will end with four maps if you include `DEL` and `PUT`).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to avoid the `i=>` (or `()=>` in my case) in the passed functions?

Comment: You can try with a map of "by-names": `Map[String,=>String]`. Of course, the function parameter should have the same type.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code :

```
def addRoute(method:String,url:String,f:()=>String) = {     

routesmap+=(method-> (routesmap.getOrElse(method,Map[String,()=>String]()) + (url->f)))

}

def get(url:String,func:()=>String)= addRoute("GET",url,func) 

def post(url:String,func:()=>String)= addRoute("POST",url,func)


def routes() 
{
get("/wobble",()=>{"toto"})
get("/wibble",()=>{println("test")
                   "titi"})
}
```

and execute these commands

```
scala> routes
scala> routesmap.get("GET").get("/wibble")()
```

Comment: Thanks, but the point of the curried functions within the routes function was to make `get` and `post` look/feel like part of the language. I want to avoid the `()=>` syntax within the `get` and `post` if at all possible.

Comment: Incidentally, thanks for the `getOrElse` bit - I hadn't noticed I was replacing my previous map with a new one instead of adding to it.