# "Any does not take parameters" - storing Unit functions in a Scala HashMap

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to store a function in my actions HashMap.
I want this function to be `readf("coffee", 1, doTest)`

Currently I get an error trying to execute the last line,

"Any does not take parameters". How do I store a function into a HashMap, then call it at a later time?

```
var xx = 0

val values = new HashMap[String, Int]
values += "coffee" -> 2
println(values("coffee"))

val actions = new HashMap[String, Any]

def readf(valueName: String, sufficient: Int, f: () => Unit): Unit = 
  if (values(valueName) > sufficient) f() else ()

  def doTest(): Unit = {
    xx == xx + 1
    println(xx)
  }

  actions += "check_cup" -> readf("coffee", 1, doTest)

  actions("check_cup")()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a function of type `() => Unit` in your actions map you should declare the the type to be `HashMap[String, () => Unit]`.

Looking at your code, it looks like `readf` has a return value of `Unit` so:

```
actions += "check_cup" -> readf("coffee", 1, doTest)
```

is actually trying to put a mapping of `"check_cup" -> Unit` into the map. This is most likely not what you want. You probably want:

```
def readf(valueName: String, sufficient: Int, f:() => Unit): () => Unit = 
    if (values(valueName) > sufficient) f else () => Unit
```

Comment: "Detected an apparent refinemend of unit, are you missing an = sign?" on the first line (function declaration)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518289/scala-passing-functions-by-reference-without-evaluating

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
actions += "check_cup" -> readf("coffee", 1, doTest)
```

you're already evaluating the function readf and storing the "result" of Unit rather than storing the function. You want that to be:

```
actions += "check_cup" -> () => readf("coffee", 1, doTest)
```

Then you're storing a function that takes no parameters, and when it is called, just calls readf with the params you supplied.

And change the type of actions to Map[String, () => Unit]

Comment: I changed the actions type. Not enough arguments for method -> : (y: B)(String, B) on the line for actions +=

Comment: I see what you mean about evaluating the function readf already. I'm experiencing this when I chain together for example actions += "make_bread" -> readf("coffee", 1, addvf("bread", 3, ()=>Unit)) where addvf adds 3 to the value of bread, bread's value is 3 even though the readvf evaluates falsey

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518289/scala-passing-functions-by-reference-without-evaluating